# How to Setup SSL Access to DocuSign REST Servers from Websphere Process server/Applicatoin server

Tags: websphere-7, docusignapi

How to Setup SSL Access to DocuSign REST Servers from Websphere Process server/Applicatoin:
From 
hostname: demo.docusing.net
port : 443

Comment: Nobody left a comment about why this was downvoted, but I'm guessing that it's just too vague to help out. If you post more details about the problem you're having we can help more.

Answer (score 1):

You should not have to do anything special.  DocuSign uses VeriSign certs.